# Como cambiar el prefijo ID Signing Certificate de mi proyecto iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Actualmente tengo varios certificados de varias cuentas de desarrollo en mi puesto de trabajo. Tengo un proyecto que en modo desarrollo y produccion tiene un prefijo ID ( Ejemplo: ABCDEFGHIJ ) y necesito cambiarlo por otro prefijo de equipo de desarrollo ( team ID ) ( Ejemplo: ZWXERTYYHL )

He entrado a la aplicacion 'llaves' pero no aparece o no se ver donde este certificado.

Comment: ¿Porqué no te lo descargas de nuevo (con el nuevo nombre)?

Comment: A que te refieres con descargar de nuevo ? El caso es que descargo el WWDR y luego creo el certificateSingning atraves de esto creo los .cer de distribucion y desarrollo y los P12 por si son necesarios. Cuando creo el ID de aplicacion no aparece el prefijo que quiero sino otro.